# Unique value validation with Knockout-Validation plugin

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using KnockoutJS with the Knockout-Validation plugin to validate fields on a form. I'm having problems validating that a value is unique using the native validation rule - `unique`

I'm using the Editor Pattern from Ryan Niemeyer to allow the user to edit or create a `Location`. Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/Hz7au/) to see my problem in its entirety.

```
function Location(data, names) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = data.id;
    self.name = ko.observable().extend({ unique: { collection: names }});
    // other properties
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);

    // update method left out for brevity
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.locations = ko.observableArray([]);   

    self.selectedLocation = ko.observable();
    self.selectedLocationForEditing = ko.observable();

    self.names = ko.computed(function(){
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.locations(), function(item) {
            return item.name();
        });
    });  

    self.edit = function(item) {
        self.selectedLocation(item);
        self.selectedLocationForEditing(new Location(ko.toJS(item), self.types));
    };

    self.cancel = function() {
        self.selectedLocation(null);
        self.selectedLocationForEditing(null);
    };

    self.update = function(item) {
        var selected = self.selectedLocation(),
            updated = ko.toJS(self.selectedLocationForEditing()); //get a clean copy

        if(item.errors().length == 0) {
            selected.update(updated);
            self.cancel();
        }
        else
            alert("Error");        
    };

    self.locations(ko.utils.arrayMap(seedData, function(item) {
        return new Location(item, self.types, self.names());
    })); 
}
```

I'm having an issue though. Since the `Location` being edited is "detached" from the `locations` observableArray (see `Location.edit` method), when I make changes to `name` in the detached `Location` that value isn't updated in the `names` computed array. So when the validation rule compares it to the `names` array it will always return a valid state of true since the counter will only ever be 1 or 0. (Please see knockout-validation algorithm below)

Within the options argument for the `unique` validation rule I can pass in a property for `externalValue`. If this value is not undefined then it will check to see if the count of matched names is greater or equal to 1 instead of 2. This works except for cases when the user changes the name, goes on to another field, and then goes back to the name and wants to change it back to the original value. The rule just sees that the value already exists in the `names` array and returns a valid state of false.

Here is the algorithm from knockout.validation.js that handles the `unique` rule...

```
function (val, options) {
    var c = utils.getValue(options.collection),
        external = utils.getValue(options.externalValue),
        counter = 0;

    if (!val || !c) { return true; }

    ko.utils.arrayFilter(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(c), function (item) {
        if (val === (options.valueAccessor ? options.valueAccessor(item) : item)) { counter++; }
    });
    // if value is external even 1 same value in collection means the value is not unique
    return counter < (external !== undefined && val !== external ? 1 : 2);
}
```

I've thought about using this as a base to create a custom validation rule but I keep getting stuck on how to handle the situation when the user wants go back to the original value.

I appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to **not include the** `name` of the currently edit item (of course when creating a new item you need the full list) in the unique validator.

So the unique check won't be triggered when changing the Location name back to its original value:

```
self.namesExceptCurrent = function(name){
    return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.locations(), function(item) {
        if (item.name() !== name)
            return item.name();
    });
}

self.edit = function(item) {
    self.selectedLocation(item);
    self.selectedLocationForEditing(
        new Location(ko.toJS(item), 
        self.types, 
        self.namesExceptCurrent(item.name())));
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/38pk2m69/)

Comment: Yes but I can handle a new item by calling `self.selectedLocationForEditing(new Location({}, self.types, self.namesExceptCurrent('')));`. This is an elegant, simple solution - Thanks nemesv!